# How can I change the display order using the elements of two seperate children divs?

Tags: html, css

The HTML-structure looks like this:

```
<div class="main-parent">
    <div class="column-left">
        <div class="1">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="2">
          2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
        <div class="3">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="4">
          4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.main-parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.1 {
  order:4;
}
.2 {
  order:3;
}
.3 {
  order:2;
}
.4 {
  order:1;
}
```

I can't seem to change the order since the main parent which has display flex, has two different children div's.

How do I make this work without removing the left and right column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox *can* do this but **usually** not with children of different parents.

However, if you can override the `display` property of the parents to `display:contents` *then* the children can be re-ordered.

> **contents**
>
> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Support is pretty good now (no IE) - see [**CanIUse**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

*Essentially, `display:contents` make the "box" of the parent disappear and the children then become flex-items of the grandparent.*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.child {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1em;
}

.grand {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.moved {
  order: 2;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.parent {
  display: contents;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child moved"> Child 1.1 Moved
    </div>
    <div class="child"> Child 1.2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Child 2.1
    </div>
    <div class="child"> Child 2.2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know what? This is actually the real answer to my problem. It's not that I was trying to reorder the left and right column, instead I wanted to change the order of the elements inside of those two columns combined together. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making display flex on column-right and column-left also. Please take a look at the updated code. It may help you.

```css
.main-parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.column-left {
  order: 2;
}
.column-right {
  order: 1;
}

.column-left,
.column-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.column-left .box-one {
  order: 2;
}
.column-left .box-two {
  order: 1;
}
.column-right .box-three {
  order: 2;
}
.column-right .box-four {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-parent">
    <div class="column-left">
        <div class="box-one">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="box-two">
          2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
        <div class="box-three">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="box-four">
          4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a good idea to use the flex display.
You can change the flex-direction of your containers when you pass over the mobile device using media queries.

cf :

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Something like :

```css
.c {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .main-parent{
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-parent">
    <div class="column-left">
        <div class="c 1">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="c 2">
          2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
        <div class="c 3">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="c 4">
          4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, good luck with the rest! ;)